# remove a model and all its versions from cloud-ml

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

Apparently there is not an easy way to remove a model from `cloud-ml`, not with the `UI` or using the python `API`. Does anybody know a fast way to remove a model with all its versions from `cloud-ml` ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a python function to remove a model from `cloud-ml` and all its versions. Its messy, but works.

```
from googleapiclient import discovery
from googleapiclient import errors
import time

def remove_model_cloud_ml (model_name:str, gc_project_id:str):

    project_id = 'projects/{}'.format(gc_project_id)
    model_id = '{}/models/{}'.format(project_id, model_name)

    ml = discovery.build('ml','v1')
    request = ml.projects().models().versions().list(parent=model_id)
    response = request.execute()

    # check if model has versions
    if 'versions' in response.keys():    
        versions = response['versions']
        while len(versions) >= 1:
            for version in response['versions']:
                request = ml.projects().models().versions().delete(name = version['name'])
                try:
                    request.execute()
                except errors.HttpError as err:
                    reason = err._get_reason()
                    if 'Cannot delete the default version' in reason:
                        next

            request = ml.projects().models().versions().list(parent=model_id)
            response = request.execute()
            time.sleep(1)
            try:
                versions = response['versions']
            except:
                break

    # remove the model         
    request = ml.projects().models().delete(name=model_id)

    # make the call to remove
    while True:    
        try:
            response = request.execute()
            # Any additional code on success goes here (logging, etc.)
        except errors.HttpError as err:
            # Something went wrong, print out some information.
            print('There was an error deleting the model.' +
                  ' Check the details:')
            reason = err._get_reason()
            print(reason)
            # Wait for 1000 milliseconds.
            if 'A model with versions cannot be deleted' in reason:
                # this probably means that the last delete version call 
                # has not yet completed, so wait and retry 
                time.sleep(1) 
                continue
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

For deleting a model you need to delete first the versions [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/managing-models-jobs#managing_versions) and then the model [[2]](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/managing-models-jobs#managing_models). In order to do so you need to follow this:

1. Delete all NOT DEFAULT versions from a model, so you end up with just one version.
2. Delete that last version (the default one).
3. Delete the model.

You can achieve that by using the UI, command lines or the API. All the info needed and the commands are on the links I provided.

Answer (score 1):

The ways suggested above are the correct ways of deleting a model, i.e. versions first (non-default, then default) and then the model itself. We are aware that this  might be cumbersome and are working towards making this interface easier for our users. One way could be to have something that basically recursively deletes the versions and models. Are there other ways this can be done that will be more suitable?

Answer (score 1):

There is one command you can do in the cloud shell:

```
gcloud ai-platform versions list --model=NAMEOFYOURMODEL|xargs -n 1 gcloud ai-platform versions delete --model=NAMEOFYOURMODEL--quiet
```